# MHartl Tutorial Error: undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

So I'm working my way through the MHartl Rails Tutorial and it has been awesome so far, albeit I have just ran into my first error and I am having trouble finding a working solution.

**The error:**

```
 NoMethodError in Users#new

Showing /Users/myname/Sites/rails_projects_updated/first_app/app/views/users/new.html.erb where line #6 raised:

undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Extracted source (around line #6):

3: 
4: <div class="row">
5:   <div class="span6 offset3">
6:     <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
7: 
8:       <%= f.label :name %>
9:       <%= f.text_field :name %>
```

**New.html.erb:**

```
<% provide(:title, 'Sign up') %>
<h1>Sign up</h1>

<div class="row">
  <div class="span6 offset3">
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>

      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %>

      <%= f.label :email %>
      <%= f.text_field :email %>

      <%= f.label :password %>
      <%= f.password_field :password %>

      <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

      <%= f.submit "Create my account", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

**And User Controller**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

   def create
      @user = User.new(params[:user])
      if @user.save
        # Handle a successful save.
      else
        render 'new'
      end
    end
  end
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Wheres the `new` method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you are missing the following method from your controller:

```
 def new
    @user = User.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end
```

What is happening is that when the form is responding to the create action and is hitting `render 'new'` which you do not have in this question. So that when the `new` action is rendered it will do `@user = User.new` which will enable you to create a new user.

Comment: @TonyP if this answered your question please mark it complete